# Limit of Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For the second time I've had trouble calculating this limit

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n＋2)(n＋5)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+3r-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(4n－1)}{(n＋1)(n＋4)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+3r-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(4n－2)}$$

This limit can be calculated by limitation method but it is not a smart method.

When using the inventory method, you get a result:

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n＋2)(n＋5)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+3r-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(4n－1)}{(n＋1)(n＋4)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+3r-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(4n－2)}\quad＝\sqrt[3]{4}$$

I'm looking for a clever way to calculate the limit in a straightforward way

`It is the second time that I try to ask a question on this site. I apologize if my question is not accurate.`

Comment: It's not at all clear what is supposed to be happening in the ellipses...

Comment: @Brian Hopkins No, it isn't, but I'm guessing it's
$$
\prod_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{n+3r-1}{n+3r-2}\right)
$$

Comment: First fraction is not same as second - is there $2$ or $12$ at end in denominator? Also, Is there sum or it should be product?

Comment: please formulate your fraction with product notation and without dots, or at least describe the formula with words. also, please explain what are the limitation and inventory methods?

Comment: btw have you tried taking a logarithm and expanding the summands into series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using
$$ \Gamma(x) \approx \sqrt{2 \pi} \, x^{x - 1/2} \, e^{-x} \, \left(1 + \frac{1}{12 \, x} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \right) $$
then it can be shown that
$$ \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{3}\right)} \approx \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^{-1/3}. $$

Now,
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \, \prod_{j=1}^{n} \left\{ \frac{n + 3 j -1}{n + 3 j -2} \right\} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left( \frac{n+2}{3} \right)_{n} }{ \left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)_{n} } = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{n+1}{3} \right) \, \Gamma\left( \frac{4n+2}{3} \right)}{\Gamma\left( \frac{n+2}{3} \right) \, \Gamma\left( \frac{4n+1}{3} \right)} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^{-1/3} \, \left(\frac{4 n}{3}\right)^{1/3} \right) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[3]{4} 
\end{align}
which gives
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \, \prod_{j=1}^{n} \left\{ \frac{n + 3 j -1}{n + 3 j -2} \right\} = \sqrt[3]{4}. $$